# Visual Studio Code - ModuleNotFoundError, different sys.path in terminal and VSCode?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, conda, mini-forge

I try running code in Visual Studio code but I keep getting a ModuleNotFoundError. When I run the code in my terminal or in debug mode in VS with the activated conda environment it works fine.

System: Mac M1 12.3

Conda Environment, selected in Visual Studio Code.

I have added this

```
import os
print('cwd is %s' %(os.getcwd()))
import sys
print('executable is %s' %(sys.executable))
print('path is %s' %(sys.path))
```

and running in terminal gives:

```
cwd is /Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder
executable is /Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/bin/python
path is ['/Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python38.zip', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

running in VS via **Run Python File** (upper right corner button) gives:

```
cwd is /Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder
executable is /Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/bin/python
path is ['/Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/lib/python39.zip', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/lib/python3.9', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

running in VS via ***Debug* Python File** (upper right corner button) gives:

```
cwd is /Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder
executable is /Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/bin/python
path is ['/Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python38.zip', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

I am confused - How can I get this running in VS Code?

---- Update March 23 2022:

I have three options
[image]

When I add

```
    "code-runner.executorMap": {

        "python": "$pythonPath -u $fullFileName"
        
    }
```

to

> settings.json

(see [https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2930/module-not-found-error.htm] [2](https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s2930/module-not-found-error.htm) from @Kyouya Sato)

and run **Run Code** it works and I also get

```
cwd is /Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder
executable is /Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/bin/python
path is ['/Users/USERNAME/xyz/CodeFolder', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python38.zip', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/Users/USERNAME/miniforge3/envs/conda_envNAME/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
```

without changing

> settings.json

it does also not work using **Run Code**.

**Run Python File** is not working at all.

Comment: `sys.path` should _not_ have the same value as `sys.executable`.  Did you do something to change the value?

Comment: Thx, I manually edited the names and had a copy error - I edited the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround:

1. [Set "python.terminal.activateEnvironment" to false in the settings.json.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18634#issuecomment-1060686997)
2. [Downgrade to the previous version of the extension which works fine(avoid `conda run`).](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18634#issuecomment-1061699266)
3. Try out the following VSIX which has the potential fix: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/suites/5578467772/artifacts/180581906, Use Extension: Install from VSIX command to install the VSIX.

Reason:

Conda has some problems:

1. [conda run -n MY-ENV python FILE.py uses the base interpreter
   instead of environment interpreter.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9587)
2. [Running using conda run inside already activated environment should
   be the same as running it outside](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11305)
3. [conda run does not remove base environment components from
   $PATH](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/11174)

Comment: @StefanOverFlow Have you solved the problem?

Comment: yes - '"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false' in 'settings.json' did the job! Thx!